# format string- compile time checking

Tags: c#, .net, string, string.format

Is there any way to check the format string at  compile time ?

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is a really {1} site", "stackoverflow.com", "cool");//this will run
```

//this will give an exception  as only one argument is supplied

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is a really {1} site", "stackoverflow.com");

Exception:"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
```

and if format string is not in the correct format (i.e. missing the "}" after 1 here )

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is a really {1 site", "stackoverflow.com","cool");

Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't add compile-time verification here. This is one of the down-sides to resource strings and formatting strings. You can do a few things to mitigate your problem.

1. Thoroughly unit test your public interfaces to be confident that your strings are being formatted correctly.
2. Use tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) that can perform static analysis and let you know about these problems before you run your application.
3. Things are better threes.

Answer (score 3):

While not really compile-time checking, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) can warn you in Visual Studio when the number of arguments is wrong or the format string is in the wrong format.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this.  Unit testing solves this problem.