# How to warn on bad parameter numbers within Console.Write()?

Tags: c#, .net, console

We have a program with thousands of lines such as:

```
Console.Write("{0},{1} - {2}", e1, "My custom error", e2); // Write a custom error
```

However, the following will throw an error, as "{3}" is greater than the number of parameters:

```
Console.Write("{0},{1} - {3}", e1, "My custom error", e2); // Write a custom error
```

How can I scan my entire project to pick this up at compile time?

**Update:**

Unfortunately, ReSharper won't work. I've created my own logging class, "w", which calls Console.Write and other logging behind the scenes. ReSharper picks up errors in "Console.Write", but ignores any parameters for said logging method.

**Update:**

FXCop doesn't pick up this sort of error. That's surprising - why not pick up an obvious error which will result in the entire program crashing with an exception?

**Update:**

Thanks for the tip @adudley - I ended up replacing all instances of "Console.Write" and "String.Format", in the logging class, with calls to specialized versions with try/catch for any errors. This avoids the entire program falling over if a single, rarely used logging function is called with bad parameters. I'd rather tell the program to ensure its bulletproof, rather than manually check 1000 logging functions for difficult-to-spot errors.

Comment: Of course, I could check this manually, but I tend to miss these 0.1% of the time, and as there are thousands of said lines, there is a high chance that eventually one of them will kill the entire program in the middle of its batch process (its happened twice already).

Comment: Tools like Resharper can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029003/format-string-compile-time-checking

Comment: A simple tools parsing with regular expressions should work (maybe even as a ReSharper plugin!) just fine for this scenario. Just mind that you need the number within the braces, for Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {0}", a, b, c) is valid. In essence you can catch missing parameters but not all bad format strings. Also, why not just go for NLog..?

Comment: @emaster70 Thanks for the tip - inspired by this, I ended up putting try/catch around all Console.Write and String.Format, in the logging class. Probably easier and faster compared to doing regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got to ask why would they be wrong? They should be correct at the time of typing, and if you translate them, check when importing translations (that's what we do).

Comment: You've updated your question. Sounds like you just need to put some custom code in your own logging method to check for this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I've added try/catch around all Console.Write and String.Format calls in the logging class.

Answer (score 2):

The commercial [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) plugin automatically finds exactly that error (I think you need to turn on project-wide inspection though). A free trial exists.

Comment: Thanks. The setting is in "Code Inspection", "Settings", "Analyze errors in whole solution".

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's probably some huge, un-tested (possibly un-testable!) legacy app but I'll throw a word in for unit tests (eg NUnit) - you can use them with a good test-doubles library (like Rhino.Mocks) to throw various errors and exercise all these lines.  The errors will show up as test failures until fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

Static code analysis can do that for you. If you have at least the Premium version of Visual Studio, you can enable it in your project settings. Otherwise you can use [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) to check your assemblies after build.

Both tools have a built-in rule, that should meet your requirement: [Provide correct arguments to formatting methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182361.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, FxCop won't pick up this sort of error, even if it occurs in an obvious place such as Console.Write(). I'll try the Premium version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a perfect opportunity for a bit of refactoring (if you can take the time to do it, of course - if there are thousands of instances of this, it may take a while ;) )

Instead of doing the same Write operation in thousands of places, why not create a static method that will output the error message, for example...

```
public static void ShowError(string e1, string e2)
{
    // possibly check for null / empty parameters if you need to.
    Console.Write("{0},{1} - {2}", e1, "My custom error", e2);
}
```

and replace the instances with

```
ShowError(e1, e2);
```

This gives you the flexibility to do more in the method than just outputting to the console - you may want to log the error as well...  You then only need to update a single method to output in a different format / to another location.

Additionally, you will get compile errors if you try to call the method with an incorrect number / type of parameters.